# What would happen if we put Schrödinger inside the box and the cat opened the box door?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, schroedingers-cat

Schrödinger's cat is a thought experiment, sometimes described as a paradox, devised by Austrian physicist Erwin Schrödinger in 1935. It illustrates what he saw as the problem of the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics applied to everyday objects.

The hypothetical scenario is that you put a live cat in an explosion-proof box with a bomb. Until you open the box, you'll have no idea if the bomb exploded and the cat died, or maybe the bomb didn’t explode and the cat is still alive.

What would happen if we put Schrödinger inside the box and the cat opened the box door?

Comment: The door would open?

Comment: Schrödinger passed away in 1961, so the experiment is not possible. On the theoretical side, we have no good model of Schrödinger, so we cannot even solve the problem numerically.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin: *Schrödinger passed away in 1961* - are you certain about that? :-)

Comment: This is a thought experiment, imagine that he is still alive, at his own time

Comment: And the cat will randomly open the box at right time

Comment: FWIW, Schrödinger was a cat lover, he chose a cat for this thought experiment to elicit sympathy for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thought experiment means that in the box the cat may be living safely or is already dead, but it is beyond our capability to predict the condition of the cat among above two situations. So, the probability of predicting that the cat is alive or not is same and has the value of--->$$\frac{1}{2}=0.5 $$So, it doesn't matter who is in the box or what is in the box, until we are opening the box and examine(observe) or in other words if we observe it by classical apparatus we will get either of the two above discussed situations. Quantum Mechanically we can say that the cat must be in a state in the box which is the superposition of the two states--->(i)In state **1** it is perfectly alive and, (2) In the state **2** it is already dead. So, when we will observe it the this two above mentioned states will collapsed into a single state which will either give the alive cat or dead cat. So, you can see it only depends on the the observer what he or she will see, in other words it doesn't depend on the things that is put inside the box. So, according to your question it is totally the same probabilistic situation what the cat will see.